# How is IF( object ) evaluated? Follows from SD card example sketch

Tags: c++, sd-card

The "DumpFile.ino" example sketch from the SD library tries to open a file off an SD card, read its contents, and write them to the Serial Monitor. I am confused in how the following `if()` statement is evaluated:

```
File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt");

if (dataFile) {
// read and print, then close
}
else {
// print error message
}
```

There must be some implicit conversion on `dataFile` which depends on whether or not `SD.open("myFile.txt")` was successful. I would like to understand how this implicit conversion occurs. Which property of the `File` object determines if the `if()` statement evaulates `true` or `false`?

Comment: It calls the `bool()` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an operator bool which does the test:

```
File::operator bool() {
  if (_file) 
    return  _file->isOpen();
  return false;
}
```

When used inside an `if` the compiler invokes the `operator bool()` which does the test you see above.

Comment: Thanks, it is obvious now that I see it. I've indeed found that this defined in the File implementation.